# Problem logging into chat

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat, login

I'm logged into several SE sites and in the past chat did worked for me. However since some time it refuses to log me in stating I'm not logged on any SE site. I've tried both with Fx and WebKit Epiphany.

There is no problem with tavern.

**Edit**: After logging out everywhere and logging in on SE site pressing log in in chat it says that my data auth is too old as oppose to previous behavior of logging indefinitly.

Global auth stopped working about the same time.

Comment: What is "Fx" and "WebKit Epiphany"? We support: IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera when possible. Anything else is use at your own risk.

Comment: This was discussed on [chat.MSO](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/chat-se-troubleshooting) for a bit.  (Fx = Firefox)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in Epiphany; it's sending invalid invalid requests in certain edge cases. These requests are rejected by the server. We may be able to implement a workaround; until then, I'm afraid you have to use a different browser.

I have [filed a bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=634513) against Epiphany regarding this issue.

Comment: Hmm. How would bug in Epiphany affect Firefox?

Comment: @Maciej Piechotka: Are you using a *recent* version of Firefox? It appears older version of FF had the same problem. Also, please check if our new [GlobalAuth Help & Test page](http://chat.stackexchange.com/globalauth-help) finds any issues.

Comment: @balpha: I've had similar problems (chat works for SO, SU, and SF, but never worked for SX) with Firefox 3.6.12 on Mac OS Tiger, although I haven't been diligent about flushing all login info, so I can't rule out corrupted session data on my side.

Comment: @balpha: 2.6.12 - so the newest stable.

Comment: @Maciej Piechotka: I assume you mean 3.6.12. What are the results of the test page?

Comment: @balpha: Link to test is broken.

Comment: @Maciej ah yes, we changed the route yesterday. http://chat.stackexchange.com/help It's also linked from the login page.

Comment: @balpha: Both passes.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it was [chat.MSO](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/) or [chat.SO](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) that worked? [chat.SE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) uses a different login, that is more dependent on the single-sign-on. I'll update the login page, but this *in turn* is mainly interested in **when** you logged in.

So try logging out completely from your preferred site, and log back in. **Then** go to chat.SE. Please do let me know either way.

Comment: I've logged out from SE, SO etc.

Comment: @Maciej - and what happens? does chat.SO work? does chat.SE work?

Comment: @Marc: chat.SO always worked. char.SE still does not work (instead of loading indefinitly it displays message about too old auth).

Comment: @Maciej - it *sounds* like the localstorage hasn't cleared. Can you try a "log out everywhere"? Sorry to be a pain, but I can't repro from here... it keeps working :(

Comment: @Marc: No problem. I reproduce the correct behaviour on Chrome. I'll try Linux next.

Comment: @Marc: It works now on Windows but it won't on any browser on Linux.

Comment: @Maciej - which *nix? I'm firing up my dual-boot ubuntu 10.10 to check a few...

Comment: worked perfectly in Chrome

Comment: I wonder if you have something getting blocked by noscript?

Comment: worked perfectly in FireFox 3.6.11

Comment: installing Epiphany...

Comment: @Marc: Gentoo. Evenrything unlocked. It worked before and I haven't done any update of Fx.

Comment: indeed it fails on epiphany; we'll look into that to see if there is a simple fix

Comment: Any update? It still does not work on Firefox.